# How to get submap of LinkedHashMap by element index?

Tags: java

I am trying to get a submap of `LinkedHashMap` based on element index. Am I reinventing the wheel here? Sounds like this should be somewhere in API already:

```
public <K,V> LinkedHashMap<K,V> subMap(LinkedHashMap<K,V> map, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    LinkedHashMap<K,V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();

    int i=0;
    for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(i >= fromIndex && i < toIndex) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Is this the way to go or there are some other better/existing solutions (within Java 6 API).

Comment: How will the returned `Map` be used? Can you use an iterator instead? If so, you could return a custom iterator that returns values (or Map.Entries) between the specified index range. Keep in mind concurrency issues when dealing with index ranges of a collection.

Answer (score 1):

[NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) allows you to get a sub-map back, but it requires that you specify a 'from key' and a 'to key', so you can't do it purely on index.

I'm not aware of any other way of doing this via the standard API.

Comment: Actually any SortedMap will provide submap(...)